# How to retrieve coordinates of PointDrawTool in Bokeh?

Tags: python, pandas, callback, bokeh

I'm trying to get **xy** coordinates of points drawn by the user. I want to have them as a dictionary, a list or a pandas DataFrame.

I'm using **Bokeh 2.0.2** in **Jupyter**. There'll be a background image (which is not the focus of this post) and on top, the user will create points that I could use further.

Below is where I've managed to get to (with some dummy data). And I've commented some lines which I believe are the direction in which I'd have to go. But I don't seem to get the grasp of it.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, Column, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import PointDrawTool, ColumnDataSource, TableColumn, DataTable
output_notebook()
```

```
my_tools = ["pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset"]

#create the figure object
p = figure(title= "my_title", match_aspect=True,
           toolbar_location = 'above', tools = my_tools)

seeds = ColumnDataSource({'x': [2,14,8], 'y': [-1,5,7]}) #dummy data
renderer = p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source = seeds, color='red', size=10)
columns = [TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
           TableColumn(field="y", title="y")]

table = DataTable(source=seeds, columns=columns, editable=True, height=100)

#callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=seeds), code="""
#    var data = source.data;
#    var x = data['x']
#    var y = data['y']
#    source.change.emit();
#""")
#
#seeds.x.js_on_change('change:x', callback)

draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer])
p.add_tools(draw_tool)
p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

show(Column(p, table))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation at https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#pointdrawtool:

> The tool will automatically modify the columns on the data source corresponding to the x and y values of the glyph. Any additional columns in the data source will be padded with the declared empty_value, when adding a new point. Any newly added points will be inserted on the ColumnDataSource of the first supplied renderer.

So, just check the corresponding data source, `seeds` in your case.

The only issue here is if you want to know exactly what point has been changed or added. In this case, the simplest solution would be to create a custom subclass of `PointDrawTool` that does just that. Alternatively, you can create an additional "original" data source and compare `seeds` to it each time it's updated.

Comment: Thanks Eugene! I did read the documentation and I thought that the above would work too. Unfortunately, when I look at the `seeds.data` I still just get the initial input `{'x': [2, 14, 8], 'y': [-1, 5, 7]}` but none of the new inputs.

Comment: "When I look at the `seeds.data`" - but when do you look at it? Inside the CustomJS callback?

Comment: Add `seeds.js_on_change('data', CustomJS(code="console.log(cb_obj.data);"))` to your code, you will see the updated data printed out in the JS console.

Comment: Hi Eugene, sorry for my not so clear communication. When I said " I look at the `seeds.data`" I meant that in a different Jupyther cell I execute `seeds.data` to inspect what's contained in seeds and only get the original input.

Comment: I have always seen the updated table printed underneath my chart. And although I managed to include you recommended snippet, nothing really seems to change. I can still see the updated table on the output of the original cell BUT when calling `seeds` I still only get the original input, NOT the  coordinates from the new points drawn with the `draw_tool`

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example. As a single code block that can be pasted into and run as a single Python file. Notebooks are intrinsically a mess, so something not working there doesn't really tell anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the execute it in Python. But show create a static version. Here is a simple example that fix it! I removed the table and such to make it a bit cleaner, but it will also work with it:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import PointDrawTool
output_notebook()

#create the figure object
p = figure(width=400,height=400)

renderer = p.scatter(x=[0,1], y=[1,2],color='red', size=10)
draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer])
p.add_tools(draw_tool)

p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

# This part is imporant
def app(doc):
    global p
    doc.add_root(p)

show(app) #<-- show app and not p!
```

[image]